# How to convert Objective C textual (po) representation to real object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, serialization

In xcode you can use po object  to see a textual representation of a given object.  Is it possible to  convert from this textual representation to a real objective c object?

Thanks

Comment: I have am existing service that I am trying to refactor.. Part of my refactor I'd to create a mock / fake / stub that returns exactly what my service returns now but without doing any work that the original service will do. Problem is there are calls to the service that return ALOT of data.. I am looking for an easy way to get the data to return fr the drubbed service.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you could parse out the address, assign it to a pointer, and retrieve the object from memory that way, but that ***IS A HORRIBLY BAD IDEA AND YOU SHOULD NEVER DO THAT***.

Real question:  what are you trying to do?

Comment: Yeah... what Dave said. Do not **ever** write code that relies upon the string returned from the `-description` method.  Down that path lies madness.

Comment: truer.. but in my case I want to create a fake object that retuns the same thing as the real object. Without the real object doing anywork. Essentially  serialize the real object... deserialize to a new object.  I want to deserialze to an object in a test run not on actual production code.

Answer (score 1):

I have a project that may inspire you, its on [GitHub](https://github.com) and its called [NDJSON](https://github.com/nathanday/ndjson). Basically it uses runtime introspection to get properties an object has and set those properties using a json key of the same value. You could do something like that but get the property values instead of set. To help in situation where the type can not be determined like the type of objects to go in a collection or to map a json key to differently named property I have defined an informal protocol that has some methods that return dictionary mapping json key to property names or class to use for property name, there are also method to return a list of json keys to ignore or alternatively the only keys to accept. If you look at my [code](https://github.com/nathanday/ndjson) on git hub there is a class called [NDJSONDeserializer](https://github.com/nathanday/ndjson/blob/master/NDJSON/NDJSON/NDJSONDeserializer.h) which contains this logic. There is a function called getTypeNameFromPropertyAttributes() which parses out the string result of Apples runtime method property_getAttributes() which you will want to look at.

Answer (score 0):

No, the representation you see from `po <instance>` is the result of `-[<instance> debugDescription]`, which by default returns `-[<instance> description]`, as described in http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html.

Unless the instance you're dealing with just happens to provide a description which is a serialized form of itself, you're SOL. Most objects don't.

The real question, as Dave points out is, what are you trying to do? `po` only works in the gdb console, so I assume this is a debugging issue. In that case, do you know that the gdb console supports sending messages to instances? So you can do:

```
po [<myInstance> methodReturningAnOtherObject]
```

or

```
po [<myInstance> valueForKeyPath:@"some.long.key.path"]
```

to follow the object graph from within the debugger console.